# Laravel - Creating API - Response and Errors

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel

I'm building an API in Laravel which will be consumed by an iPhone App.  I'm using [Fractal](https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal) for transformers and [OAuth2 Server](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) for authentication.

I have the bulk of the functionality, however, I'm a little unsure of the best way to implement Error Responses, and to some degree, Responses in general.

For example, lets say a given endpoint processes a user's request to 'Follow' another User (a la Twitter).  The request will need to:

1. Check if the requesting User is logged in.
2. Check that the Userthey are requesting to follow, actually exists
3. Check that the User they are requesting to follow, isn't someone they already follow.
4. Perhaps another validation constraint (for the sake of
   this example)

So at this point, there are four different 'checks', each of which needs to return specific error messages, error codes, and status codes.

Should these be treated exceptions?  If so, how might one go about structuring Exceptions for their domain, knowing they'll need to have many down the line?

When should exceptions be used, versus just returning a non-200 status code with validation errors?

I'm also concerned that my classes which process this endpoint, will be littered with statements like `if ($this->condition) return Exception('messages and errors codes')`

Comment: A little late, but... How did you come up with this?